# Zoom in Activity Transition-Android

Tags: android, animation

I creating an application with few buttons when I click each buttons i want to go to new activity with zoom in animation from that particular clicked button frame.I achieved this by using `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_in, R.anim.zoom_out);`
Now my problem,it's not perfect in all devices I guess it's because of Pivot values how can i set this animation from button frames for all devices.

**My zoom_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >
    <scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@string/animation_duration"
    android:fromXScale="0.9999"
    android:fromYScale="0.15"
    android:pivotX="24%"
    android:pivotY="77.5%"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1" >
    </scale>
 </set>
```

**My zoom_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      >
    <scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"

    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="100%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1" >
    </scale>
 </set>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution and its worked for me paste the
below code inside button click:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Currentactivity.this,  Nextactivity.class);

                      Bundle b = null;
                      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                          //b = ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(view, 0, 0, view.getWidth(),
                          //                                         view.getHeight()).toBundle();
                          Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                          bitmap.eraseColor(Color.parseColor("#308cf8"));

                          b = ActivityOptions.makeThumbnailScaleUpAnimation(v, bitmap, 0, 0).toBundle();
                      }
                      startActivity(i, b);
```

Comment: what is v here ?